# Optimizing dev Homestead to reduce (6s) long application load times

Tags: laravel

How should I optimize my Laravel Homestead *dev* environment?

There are no shortage of articles explaining how to optimize your Laravel for *production*, but what I can't find is how to optimize my *development* - namely, what *shouldn't* I do on dev that's suggested for production? I'm assuming that caching everything on dev would be a bad idea while I'm still developing.

My debug bar currently shows these averages clicking around the pages of my application:

> Booting: 120ms-500ms
>
> Application: 6s-10s

From the sound of it, 120ms isn't too bad for booting, but obviously I need to improve my application load times.

Steps already taken:

- I've implemented winnfsd with `vagrant plugin install vagrant-winnfsd` and used `type: "nfs"` on my folders in my Homestead.yaml and `vagrant reload --provision`
- Also increased my memory in Homestead.yaml to 4096 and provisioned again. Still getting 6s+ application loads.

I guess it would help to determine specifically which parts of my application are taking the longest to load (queries, routes, etc) before I have follow-up questions on how to improve those specific parts.

Comment: 6s - 10s to load a single page?

Comment: I had this problem myself, and I solved it by changing the shares that were defined in the homestead yaml. Rather than share my app root, I shared each folder (app, bootstrap, database, etc) individually *except* the vendor folder. This folder I kept only on the VM (and had a copy locally for my IDE intellisense). It sped things up immensely. Some caveats were that I had to maintain root level file individually, but not too painful since I rarely changed them

Comment: @levi - yes, at least 6 seconds for a single page load. No better on subsequent loads, either.

Comment: @Jason - seems like an odd way to have do it, but I might as well give it a try. It would be a bummer to have to SSH in to my server any time I need to npm install, but at this point I'm kinda desperate to speed up page loads for development. Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone recommend a good target to aim to get for "Booting" and "Application" page load load times in the Laravel debug bar? What are you getting in your apps on your development server?